# Whom should I take recommendation letter from?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, united-states, recommendation-letter

I am applying for a Ph.D. position in US universities. I am confused about whom should I use as one of my recommenders? One of them is from the school from which I graduated and he is the department head, had been a postdoc in one of the US's top universities. I took one of his courses and he was my course advisor at that time.
On the other hand, another one had been my supervisor for two projects (in my workplace) and is very young (doing his first or second postdoc). We did not publish any articles yet but they are under review. So basically she can write better about my research experience and so on.
I am confused because I attended a webinar from a US school lately where the department head said they prefer LORs from someone who had been my supervisor or knows me via research, not someone who knows me via one or two courses.
Whom should I choose as one of my recommenders?

Comment: Normally going with the person who has helped you with research is better but in this case that person is still in the post-doc stage so it is better to go ahead with the department head.

Comment: First, you usually need multiple recommendations.  Second it sounds like you already got an answer but don't like it/aren't convinced?  Third, a number of such questions have already been answered here: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/171662/19607 https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/85215/19607 https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/13691/19607

Comment: yeah the rest two are already decided. I was confused between these two.

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeking entry in a research degree, then pick the researcher.  A good reference letter will often complement a transcript, especially if the referee can add to context beyond what the transcript does.  In your case the researcher can provide this additional context.